# 'Which country are you going to' or 'Which country are you going to go to'

Tags: difference

> - Which country are you going to?
> - Which country are you going to go to?

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

As with most sentences, the meaning depends on context, but the difference between them is negligible. The only difference is in nuance.

> A. "I'm travelling overseas soon."
>   B. "Which country are you going
>   to?"

This is simply asking where A is intending to go. (However, rather than "**which**," the more open-ended "**what**" would probably sound a little more natural here.)

> A. "I couldn't decide for the longest time whether to go to Japan,
>   Spain or Cuba."
>   B. "Which country are you going to go to?"

The addition of "**going to**" implies that some extra decisiveness was involved in making the decision. (But "**which country are you going to?**" would also do fine.)

Comment: "Going to" _could_ mean that you are currently on your way there. "Going to go" puts the journey definitely in the future.